# How do I bypass IdP selection in the "edit profile" policy in Azure AD B2C?

Tags: customization, edit, azure-ad-b2c, user-profile

I am integrating an "edit profile" policy into a mobile app. The starting scenario is that the user is already signed in, either with a local (email) account or a social account.

Whenever I invoke the "edit profile" policy from the app, it first displays an IdP selection page. Since the user is already signed in, this is extremely confusing for the user, and unnecessary. Furthermore, if the user is signed in with a local account, she is forced to enter her credentials again.

How can I configure the B2C policy (or the app) such that the user gets straight to the actual profile editing page?

Comment: You mean you want to configure the B2C policy to make the local account can straight to profile editing policies page without entering credentials again?

Comment: Correct. Since the user is already signed in, both the IdP selection and the subsequent sign in are superfluous and confusing.

Answer (score 0):

You bypass it by removing the `prompt=login` parameter from the policy URL.

Test it like this:

1. Open a new browser, and use the `sign in` journey and login.
2. Open a new tab, and paste the Profile Edit link, remove the
   `prompt=login` query parameter.
3. Open the link and you are taken straight to the Edit Profile page, rather than seeing a sign in page.