# How to register MSAL JS callback for the custom B2C Invite policy?

Tags: angularjs, redirect, callback, azure-ad-b2c, msal.js

This question is related to this one: [AngularJS hash # problem after Azure B2C Sign Up policy redirects to application](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57062803/114029)

Here's the Invite custom policy details: https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/invite

The `Sign Up` invite process is done through e-mail, that is, the user is not using the app and clicking a link on the SPA AngularJS app.

The `Sign In` works just fine because the user gets redirected to the `Sign In` policy when they're inside the AngularJS SPA app. They actually click a button when the MSAL JS code is already configured.

For the `Sign Up` policy the user clicks the invitation link on their e-mail and this link leads to the B2C `Sign Up` policy. The user clicks the Create button and then they're redirected back to the main app's root address with an `#id_token` sent from B2C like this:

```
https://cooldev.azurewebsites.net/#id_token=tokenhere
```

The problem is that the SPA application has no callback registered to deal with this redirect from the B2C policy.

Any ideas on how to overcome this?

Comment: How did you get the invitation URL using the msal? I am not aware of if the policy directly sends the email or we need to send the email to the user?

Comment: We send the email according to the doc linked in my question above.

Comment: let me say this way,
1) how can I get the necessary token using the msal?
2) what shall be the invitation URL like?
3) does the policy directly sends the email or we need to send the email to the user?

The example is .net one and I am not much aware of it.

Comment: All steps necessary to accomplish the invitation is described in that doc. Read it carefully. In your case, you'd better ask a new question here in SO pointing your doubts and specifying your tech stack since your question is very specific to your use case. It's not something easy to explain in just a few words. It's complex. You need to read a lot about this subject. In sum: 1) MSAL acquires the token automatically after you call login(). 2) described in the doc linked above. 3) we need to send the email if you implement this custom invitation policy.

Comment: okay. Will do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[That invitation sample](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/invite) that you have referred to generates [an invitation link](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/blob/97b562dae233915976f428b21ad19d5642e7361a/policies/invite/source-code/AADB2C.Invite/Controllers/HomeController.cs#L54) that is direct to the Azure AD B2C endpoint.

The main disadvantage of this invitation implementation is that the single-page application doesn't call the sign-up flow and, therefore, correlation between the sign-up request and the sign-up response isn't created.

An alternative approach is demonstrated by [this invitation sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-advanced-policies/tree/master/wingtipgamesb2c) which generates [an invitation link](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-advanced-policies/blob/372d766aadb2051ddd72daaee12e0d6de34c0206/wingtipgamesb2c/src/WingTipGamesWebApplication/Controllers/InvitationController.cs#L46) that is direct to an application endpoint and contains:

- The e-mail address of the invited user
- An invitation expiration, and
- A HMAC-based signature

When the invitation link is opened, this application endpoint [validates](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-advanced-policies/blob/372d766aadb2051ddd72daaee12e0d6de34c0206/wingtipgamesb2c/src/WingTipGamesWebApplication/Controllers/InvitationController.cs#L90) the HMAC-based signature and the invitation expiration and, if they are valid, then it redirects the invited user to the sign-up flow with the ID token.

Comment: Do you happen to know how to get this working? https://stackoverflow.com/q/52147584/114029. The idea is that the user is already signed in. In the app there'll be a button `Edit profile` that calls the `Edit Profile` custom B2C policy. We just don't need to request the user to log in again. I tried messing up with the `TrustFrameworkBase.xml` file (`ProfileEdit`) UserJourney but that didn't work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

What's the redirect uri used for the Sign In policy?  The same redirect uri should probably be used for the Invite link to the Sign Up policy.  I'm not sure why a redirect uri would work for one policy and not the other.  In both scenarios, it's just redirecting from your OIDC authority to that uri with the token info (or error message) in the hash.  You may have to set up your code that processes the hash to ignore unmatched `state`.

This redirect uri should ideally point to a lightweight html page that does *not* load the full SPA.  It should only process the hash from the authority, store the values in sessionStorage or localStorage, and then redirect to the SPA.  This should allow more prompt behavior and prevent overlapping concerns of what the hash represents.

Comment: The `Sign In` policy redirects to the root `https://cooldev.azurewebsites.net/` defined in the Reply URL @ Azure B2C app's Properties blade. From my understanding of what you mention I could add a new Reply Url @ Azure something like `https://cooldev.azurewebsites.net/signup.html`... am I right? Right now the `Sign Up` policy is also redirecting to the app's root\base path but since the policy invocation didn't start from the SPA application, it doesn't have a callback registered to handle the `#id_token` sent by B2C.

Comment: @LenielMaccaferri I edited in an afterthought: you may need to configure MSAL.js to not check the `state`, preferably only if it's coming from the Sign Up policy if possible.  I don't know if MSAL.js supports that sort of config.